# How to compute a column value in oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

```
create table ord_tbl
(
ord_id number(10) primary key,
ord_name varchar2(20),
quantity number(20),
cost_per_item number(30),
total_cost number(30)--This colm shud be (quantity*cost_per_item),
ord_date date
)
```

So when I insert rows then the 'total_cost' should automatically get generated and inserted into a table

Comment: I'd say don't put "total_cost" in the table, since its simply calculated from other columns in the row.  Besides, you'll probably change your mind about how to calculate "total cost" anyway.

Answer (score 6):

#### 10g doesn't have this feature.  Instead, use a view:

```
create table ord_tbl
(
ord_id number(10) primary key,
ord_name varchar2(20),
quantity number(20),
cost_per_item number(30),
ord_date date
);

create view vw_ord_tbl as
    select ord_id, ord_name, quantity, cost_perId, (quantity*cost_per_item) as total_cost, ord_date
    from ord_tbl;
```

The alternative would be to have the column in the table to maintain the value using a trigger -- for both updates and inserts.  I would suggest using the view, because maintaining the triggers adds a lot of maintenance overhead.

EDIT (by Jason):

In 11g you can create a virtual column in the table definition.

```
create table ord_tbl (
    ord_id number(10) primary key,
    ord_name varchar2(20),
    quantity number(20),
    cost_per_item number(30),
    total_cost as (quantity*cost_per_item),
    ord_date date
)
```

Comment: @beherenow . . . I'm a fan of putting that information in the tags.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @gordon lineoff thnx,it's working fine but for every time to see the total cost i must hav to look into a view which i created..wht if i wnato store that calculated values in the main table database "ord_tbl",,,jus wanted to knw that is there any way to do this

Comment: @user1334522_Bhavin . . . Actually, you would just regularly use the view instead of the table.  This can be a useful practice, especially when you want to add, remove, or rename columns in tables without having to change queries in applications.

Answer (score 2):

Like Gordon Linoff answered, you can create a view. Alternatively you can create a trigger and store the actual value:

```
create trigger tiua_ord_tbl
on ord_tbl after insert or update
for each row
begin
  :new.total_cost := :new.quantity * :new.cost_per_item;
end;
```

The advantage of storing the data, is that you can access it faster and index it if you need. The disadvantage is that you store redundant data (it can be calculated at runtime) and it requires more storage space.

I would advise to use the view at first, and only start storing the value in the table if you need this 'cached' version for performance.