# Sum and insert automatically in sql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table in my db

### a | b | c

1 | 1 | 2

 1 | 2 | 3

 2 | 3 | 5
 
2 | 4 | 6

for example.
i'd like to know if i can make kind of a table which if i input some number (directly in sql) in column a and b, it will sum and insert it into table c by itself.
it is fine to make it in view

Comment: You can refer below stack overflow link (for Oracle 10g)

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946326/how-to-compute-a-column-value-in-oracle-10g>

Comment: What do you want exactly? 3 different tables? 3 columns in a table?

Comment: 3 column in a table, and if i input the value of a and b, it will sum and column c with show the result directly and automatically

Comment: You can do this using triggers. Set up a trigger after insert that that sums the first 2 columns and puts the resulting value in the 3rd column

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy, it can be any table it's just about your INSERT query.
Query for that should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO t1(a, b, c)
VALUES (inA, inB, inA + inB)
```

Note: inA and inB are two values you want to insert, inA + inB is sum of that number which will be inserted into third column!

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9a4/1) to see how that's work...

GL!

Comment: but, i insert it by filling the column, no query