# How to get fixed CREATE_DATE and varying UPDATE_DATE in ETL?

Tags: sql, informatica

I want to load two columns `CREATE_DATE` and `UPDATED_DATE` in every table in database.  `CREATE_DATE` should tell me the date/time when the initial one-time full dataload happened but `UPDATED_DATE` should change based on every incremental load. What could be the best way to do this without changing the mappings? Any SQL function or query that can do this dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why you're avoiding changing the mapping logic... here you have a tool tailor made for this sort of processing. if you have means in the mapping already to tell inserts and updates apart then you just use SYSTIMESTAMP in an expression and decide between 2 targets, connecting to CREATE_DATE And UPDATED_DATE FOR INSERTS and just UPDATED_DATE for updates.

If you insist on using SQL then look at Gordon's post here [How to compute a column value in oracle 10g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946326/how-to-compute-a-column-value-in-oracle-10g) but know that there are performance penalties for setting triggers on your database